# Running Azure Node.js app locally - connecting to same database

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

Is it possible to run an Azure Node.js App Service locally, but connect to the same cloud SQL database?

If so, when connecting to the locally running service, how do you connect a client to the local service? Assuming a client is connecting via an HTML/javascript app, the normal code would be `client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('https://myservice.azurewebsites.net');` <-- do you just change that url to the IP the local server is running on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to get an Azure Mobile App running locally.

You just need to pull the repo from Azure to your local, and then run `npm install` command under the root folder (which includes `package.json` file). After all npm packages are installed you should run the following command to start the local Node.js server:

```
set SQLAZURECONNSTR_MS_TableConnectionString=<mssql_connection_string>&& node app.js
```

---

Now, on the client side, change your connection reference to something like this:

```
client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('http://localhost:3000');
```

and change the CSP HTTP header as below from the `index.html`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: http://localhost:3000; style-src 'self'; media-src *">
```

For more information, please refer to https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/01/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-2-local-development/

Comment: Just want to confirm that when I follow these steps, my locally running node server will still be connected to my Azure database?

Comment: Yes, it will be connected to your Azure database after you set the environment variable `SQLAZURECONNSTR_MS_TableConnectionString`.

Comment: I've actually only finally gotten around to this, and I've hit a snag. I've set the environment variable but I'm getting the error `ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'User'.` I've checked and checked and I'm sure that I'm using the same SQL login details as the live server. I made sure to add appropriate firewall whitelist to make sure my local server is able to access it (before I did that I was getting a different error). I don't know what's going wrong.

Comment: actually I got it to work, made a silly error. THANK YOU AARON