# Creating a local azure mobile app service environment for testing

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services, development-environment

I have a xamarin forms application which has offline sync, using an azure mobile app service. I'm currently publishing the app to azure every time I make changes, but with other people starting to work on the same project there is a need to have individual instances of the app service for each person, rather than us all trying to debug the same service (hitting each others break points).
I've had a look around and there's no documentation on setting up a local azure testing environment on my pc for an app service, that will need to be access externally by mobile clients. Does anyone have any experience with this and could you give me some pointers please?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the .NET or Node version of the backend? Microsoft has a [documentation page](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/wiki/Local-development-and-debugging-the-Mobile-App-.NET-server-backend) for running the .NET Mobile App service locally. For the Node service please see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46950519/running-azure-node-js-app-locally-connecting-to-same-database) or [30 days of Zumo v2](https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/01/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-2-local-development/).